# gameObject and col.gameObject both get destroyed

Tags: c#, gameobject

I want a square[0] to be destroyed by triangles(tag = 2) and circles(tag = 3) when the square comes into contact with them.

Also I want square[0] to destroy square(tag = 1) and not be destroyed itself.

The code bellow destroys both square[0] and any other object it comes in contact with.

Also if there is a more efficient way to put this please tell me. As on the actual script I am dealing with 9 tagged objects and 9 array objects.

My question is: Does my code read "If player is square and it collides with a triangle(tag = 2) or circle(tag = 3) then destroy the square[0] and if square[0] collides with square(tag = 1) then destroy square(tag = 1)"?

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D col) 
{
  if (player[0] && (col.gameObject.tag == "2" || col.gameObject.tag == "3" )) 
  { 
    Destroy (gameObject); 
  } 
  if (player[0] && col.gameObject.tag == "1") 
  { 
    Destroy(col.gameObject); 
  }
}
```

Comment: I can guess that you're unable to debug this because it's a mess. Rethink your logic, I'm positive you can condense this to be more understandable for yourself and others.

Comment: There is a feature in the edit bar that allows you to format the post. One of these options is for 'code'. Try it! Also, just submitting a bunch of code and no description makes it hard for us to understand what you want.

Comment: In your description, you talk about `square[0]`, but in the code it's `player[0]`. Could you edit the question and clarify this?

Comment: I have other shapes in the player array. Square is numbered [0]. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: When the player is a square, is their tag also 1? If so, you might need to check whether the `this` object receiving this collision is the player, rather than just checking that there is *some* non-null entry in `player[0]` (which will be true from the perspective of both squares, leading both to destroy each other). If not, we'll need to see more details about where this script snippet lives and how you're using your `player[]` array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All 50 lines which didn't work got cut down to about 4 lines which work. I am So Happy.

```
 void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D col) {

    if (gameObject.tag == col.gameObject.tag) {
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
    }
    else { Destroy(gameObject); }        
}
```

Thank you all who helped me out

Comment: I can not see how this code would work for the problem you describe, above. You describe having to destroy the collider or the player, based off the tags, *but in no given scenario are the two tags matching*. For example, if a square [tag 0] hits another square [tag 1], your code will compare tags 0 and 1, find them ***not equal***, and destroy the original gameobject. In your problem, you describe wanting to destroy the collider gameobject in this situation, not the original gameobject.

Comment: I simply changed all my tags.